# Display Content Query output as if it is its own Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

I have a Content Query Web Part that displays certain documents from a Document Library based on metadata.

But how can I get it to display as if it is it's own document Library? i.e. with column headings, the tick boxes to the left of the files to select them, and the ... to the right to allow people to interact with those files?

Comment: Is all the documents from the same Document Library? If so why not use a List View Web Part and get the functionality for free?

Comment: Sounds like that may be what I need. I'll look at that. It may have passed me by!

Comment: Hmmm. Can't seem to find the List View Web Part?

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks. Add it as an post and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is all the documents from the same Document Library? If so why not use a List View Web Part and get the functionality for free?

(Since Per never got around to it.)